# Duplicate Website with different theme?

Tags: theming

I would like to create a duplicate of my existing website (includes all content) and apply a different theme.

So for example I would have www.widgets.com with one theme & products.widgets.com with the same content but a totally different theme.

Also, when I add/update/delete content in www.widgets.com I would like it to change in products.widgets.com.

What's the best way to accomplish this? I'm using Drupal 6.

Thanks-in-advance

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at [themekey](http://drupal.org/project/themekey) module.

> ThemeKey allows you to define simple or sophisticated theme-switching rules which allow automatic selection of a theme depending on current path, taxonomy terms, language, node-type, and many, many other properties.

One other property is "host", which would fit into your demands, although this wouldn't be actually a copy of your site. Instead you would just switch the theme on another domain. (On a side note you should consider avoiding "duplicate content" for better serach results.)

Comment: Thanks, does themekey allow changing theme based on URL?

Comment: Also, I was thinking of setting up a Drupal Multi-Site http://drupal.org/documentation/install/multi-site

Comment: I'm not sure if ThemeKey let you change the theme based on domain, but if not, you can use [Domain Access](http://drupal.org/project/domain).

Domain access let you choice the theme based on domain.

Comment: ThemeKey works great! Switched the theme, with some minor tweeks, based on the incoming URL.

Comment: I still have one related issue with Themekey